# Struggling writing a nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following tables:

```
   Products:

+---------------------------+
|id|name |details  |price|cn|
|__|_____|_________|_____|__|
| 1|pen  |somethi  |100  |10|
| 2|paper|something|30   |11|
+---------------------------+

Categories:

+----------------------------+
|id | name      |parent_id   |
|____________________________|
|1  | granny    | 0          |
|2  | dad       | 1          |
|3  | grandson  | 2          |
|4  | grandson 2|  2         |
+----------------------------+

Products2categories:

+-------------------------------+
| id  | product_id | category_id|
|_______________________________|
| 1   | 1          | 3          |
| 2   | 1          | 2          |
| 3   | 1          | 1          |
+-------------------------------+
```

I want to do a query that will return all of the categories that some product is related to.

for example: 
When I supply a product ID of `1` I would like to get as a result the result
grandson,dad,granny (name of the categories that this product is related to)

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT `categories`.`name`
FROM `categories` 
JOIN (
    SELECT `products2categories`.`category_id`,`products2categories`.`product_id`
    FROM `products2categories` a
        JOIN `products`
        ON `products`.`id` = `products2categories`.`product_id`
)

ON `categories`.`id` = `products2categories`.`category_id`
```

I've got the following error:

`Every derived table must have its own alias`

I would like to get some help here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add a table alias after the final `)` . . . as in `) t`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your statement, I believe you're overcomplicating things. Based on your verbal description of what you want (and ignoring your code), this will do what you're asking:

```
SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM products2categories WHERE product_id = 1);
```

**EDIT: HERE IS A COMPLETE TEST**

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES (1,'granny',0),(2,'dad',1),(3,'grandson',2),(4,'grandson 2',2);

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (1,'pen','somethi',100,10),(2,'paper','something',30,11);

CREATE TABLE `products2categories` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `products2categories` VALUES (1,1,3),(2,1,2),(3,1,1);

mysql> SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM products2categories WHERE product_id = 1);
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| granny   |
| dad      |
| grandson |
+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: My bad, It doesn't return 0 row, but it does return ALL of the categories names

Comment: Yeah, you said, "I want to do a query that will return all of the categories that some product is related to." So it returns of them - in this case: granny, dad, grandson, BUT NOT grandson 2

Comment: well, it did return grandson2 for some reason :o

Comment: You've got a typo somewhere then. I've amended my answer to also build the DB so you can see it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've just found out that I was doing it way too hard that it actually is.

For who-ever will come across it somewhen in the future, here is the solution:

```
SELECT `categories`.`name`
FROM `categories` 
JOIN `products2categories`
ON `categories`.`id` = `products2categories`.`category_id`
WHERE `products2categories`.`product_id` = 1
```

Comment: Except this isn't actually the right way to do it. Per http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:66812779016023 you should use a subselect, not a join.